# Magento & Varnish / Turpentine, Zero-hit rate

Tags: magento, varnish

we have some strange problems with (nginx), magento(1.9.0.1), turpentine and varnish(3.0.2), running on Ubuntu 12.04lts. **We aren't 2 experienced with varnish/turpentine, so this might be a basic thing.**

We got the turpentine vcl successfully **applied to the running varnish instance**, and checked the result with `varnishadm vcl.list`. We also enabled debug info in turpentine.

**Strange thing:**

If we activate both turpentine caching methods in magento backend->cache, especially the fpc, we got the following response

```
Server  nginx
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Via 1.1 varnish
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15
X-Turpentine-Cache  0
X-Turpentine-Esi    1
X-Varnish   293774805
X-Varnish-Hits  0
```

**and a real bad response time of 3.5sec** cause the page never seems to get cached as you can see clearly in X-Turpentine-Cache and X-Varnish-Hits. There's also no age set in header.

But if we deactivate the turpentine fpc, while letting the vcl untouched we get

```
Age 29
Server  nginx
Via 1.1 varnish
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15
X-Varnish   293775151 293775096
X-Varnish-Hits  2
```

combined with the optimized resonse time about 100ms, this seems to be a hit.

What point are we missing to setup turpentine/varnish the right way, what is causing the zero hit rate with activated turpentine caching?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you enable all caches in Mageto?

Comment: Yes, all internal ones. I disabled memcached etc.

Comment: And of course there's no other external fullpagecache running...

Comment: "Server nginx" in both headers makes me think something is wrong with your configuration. i dont see a full picture, so this question is only guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some steps to troubleshoot:

**Get Varnish Working on its own:**

Your `varnishd` should be running with several parameters, here's samples from my Ubuntu Server install (`/etc/defaults/varnish`):

- `-a :6081` public port -- this is the port webbrowsers will use
- `-T localhost:6082` admin port -- this is used to configure varnish
- `-f /etc/varnish/default.vcl` initial VCL config file (see below) -- the configuration used when varnish first starts
- `-s malloc,256m` storage backend -- a 256MB in-memory backend in this case
- `-S /etc/varnish/secret` path to varnish's admin password file

Turpentine's [documentation](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/wiki/Installation) also mentions these parameters are likely required:

- `-p esi_syntax=0x2`
- `-p cli_buffer=16384`

Here's my sample `default.vcl`, this is a barebones config that tells Varnish to proxy requests to 127.0.0.1:80, and wil only be used until Turpentine reconfigures Varnish:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "80";
}
```

You can verify these settings are in-use by checking the running process: `ps aux |grep varnishd`

**Testing your Varnish config**

With varnishd running with the above parameters you should be able to telnet to your admin port (`-T` above):

```
telnet localhost 6082
```

If you provided `-S` above you will be prompted for authorization; use the contents of your secret file.  If you can't get in via telnet try removing the `-S` parameter to disable authentication (you'll want to re-enabled it later).  Once you login you'll be at the varnish console; keep this open.

**Setting up Turpentine**

I assume you've successfully installed Turpentine in Magento.  Go to `System -> Configuration` and review these settings:

- Varnish Options

  - Varnish Version: Set to "Auto" if you don't know the specific version you're using
  - Server List: this should exactly match the `-T` parameter for `varnishd` -- `localhost:6082` in the above example
  - Varnish Authentication Key: this should be the key used for `-S` above, or empty if you've disabled authentication
- Caching Options

  - Backend Host: `localhost` if Magento and Varnish are on the same server, otherwise the Magento host
  - Backend Port: Magento's HTTP port (typically 80)

When you save these configs you should see a success or error message.  This message indicates that Turpentine was able to generate a new VCL configuration file and make it active in Varnish.  To confirm this use your telnet session to run `vcl.list`.  You should see something like:

```
vcl.list
200 106     
available       4 boot
active          2 ef1a15f2132a599ed26520c94c599e71aa7f5e576afcfca211e6249dcd640ddd
```

`boot` is the `default.vcl` above; the second VCL is what Turpentine has generated and has been switched to be active.

- Use `System -> Cache Management` to enable both Varnish Magento caches; flush all caches and logout of the admin panel to ensure everything takes effect.

At this point Turpentine should be up and running.  You can run `varnishstats` and load your webpage using the `-a` port from `varnishd`.  Reloading the page several times should result in an above-zero Hitrate.

Keep in mind that with this configuration your Turpentine VCL will be lost if `varnishd` is restarted (along with cached contents).  You can use the `Cache Management` page of magento to export a new .acl file to use for the `-f` parameter so that it will take effect whenever varnish restarts.

Comment: You saved my life and you don't know it. My problem was the server list saying 127.0.0.1:6082 and -T localhost:6082. Thanks heaps